# How to make a n application 'high availability'

Tags: cluster-computing, high-availability

One of the jargon associated with enterprise systems is 'high availability' systems. I understand that a basic way to have a high availability system is to deploy your application as a cluster so that when one node goes down, the other ndoes can still service requests. Is there more to high availability than clustering?

Comment: Simplicity (few points of failure) and redundancy (lots of automated fail-overs when something goes wrong), basically.  Identify points of failure, set up automated ways of dealing with those failures.  Redundant network connections, multiple backup locations, etc.

Comment: But this all is already taken care of when you deploy in a cluster. IS there anything on top of this?

Comment: No it isn't.  Simplicity is a matter of how the system (both hardware and software) is designed.  Simply "using a cluster" doesn't make something simple.  And while a cluster has *some* redundancy, it doesn't cover everything.  Is the cluster all in one building?  What happens if the building burns down?  What happens if the network provider fails?  What happens if that entire area of the country experiences a blackout?  The higher you want to push the availability, the more things need to be redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's more to it than this:

One of the "hard parts" of high availability services is maintaining the data required by your application across a cluster of request-handling servers over a long period of time. This is often accomplished using databases or key-value stores and replication. There's a lot to know here.

Another challenge is directing incoming requests to least-busy request-handlers. This is often assisted using load balancing software (or hardware) like F5.

Monitoring of both handlers and data-stores becomes increasingly important as your service grows -- Splunk, nagios, etc., become critical. You'll also want to know how your cloud service's management tools work (RightScale and others provide tools that can seem pretty opaque unless you're very experienced with them and the environments they're monitoring/managing).

At the application level, you'll have a whole new set of challenges revolving around how you store and deliver static data (possibly a CDN like Akamai delivering assets stored in S3?), how your application synchronizes data-access across a cluster (like writing threaded code -- not trivial), and how best to manage the hardware resources your application requests (memory, CPU, network, etc.)

Each of these things by itself is an area of deep study.